How Can I Retrieve Information from Orphaned `.avhdx` Files When No Corresponding Hyper-V Checkpoints Exist?
I'm working with Hyper-V on a Windows system and have encountered an issue with some .avhdx files in my C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual hard disks folder. These files appear to be different disks, but their IDs (the last part of the filename) do not match any of the checkpoint IDs I can retrieve using PowerShell for my virtual machines. Specifically, I'm using the following command to fetch checkpoint IDs:
Get-VMSnapshot -VMName 'VMName' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ID

Despite this, there are .avhdx files whose names do not correspond to any of the fetched IDs, suggesting that these files might be orphaned.
I want to find out if there's a way to extract any useful information directly from these .avhdx files, considering that they don't appear in Hyper-V's current database of checkpoints. I aim to determine if these files still contain valuable data and possibly understand their origin or the context in which they were created.
Any insights on tools or methods to analyze these orphaned .avhdx files would be greatly appreciated.

Try Google on "avhdx file but no checkpoint".   File Viewer Plus. says it will open them(?).

@cliff2310 Thanks for the comment. I am looking for a native solution, preferably using cmd batch or PowerShell. I wonder if the name of the virtual machine / checkpoint is preserved anywhere inside the .avhdx file or if it is gone once it is orphaned.
